# Ansible: ansible assemble regexp to Assembles specific files

Tags: regex, ansible

I am using assemble module to make one file from multiple files. I have a list of files and from that list I want only `.pub` files to be assembled, but I am not sure how to use this.

list of files

```
root_rsa_comiskey-v01
root_rsa_comiskey-v01.pub
root_rsa_comiskey-v02
root_rsa_comiskey-v02.pub
root_rsa_comiskey-v03
root_rsa_comiskey-v03.pub
root_rsa_comiskey-v05
root_rsa_comiskey-v05.pub
```

Playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: 10.1.31.81
  become_user: yes
  tasks:
  - name: list files
    shell: ls -1 /tmp/root_ssh_key*
    register: dumpfiles

  - name: fetch files
    assemble: src=/tmp/root_ssh_key/ dest=/tmp/root_ssh_key/id_rsa regexp='(*.pub)'
    register: test

  - debug: var=test
```

Comment: capitals, sentence structure, code whitespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexp parameter is a [Python regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) – not shell glob.
If you want to join all files ending with `pub` use:

```
assemble: src=/tmp/root_ssh_key/ dest=/tmp/root_ssh_key/id_rsa regexp='pub$'
```